# How do you email users that are in a database

Tags: html, mysql, database, list, email

I have a database that stores email addresses of the people who sign up for my email list. But  now I need to know how to send mass emails without having to copy each individual email address from my PHPMYADMIN. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Do you have access to a mail server?

Comment: Yes, and the database is MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning with what method you are going to send these emails out. Using phpmyadmin, you could export the emails in various formats. Using csv, you can then use that file with multiple applications. Be a little more specific if you'd like better help.

Comment: That is the point of his question. He wants to know the best method to mass email the users in his database.

Comment: @MockY I don't really know how I want to export it. Let's say I use CSV which applications could I import it into?

Answer (score 0):

You'll really want to use an [email service provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_service_provider).

> ...a commercial ESP, is a company which offers email marketing or bulk email services. According to Spamhaus, neither of these terms is intended to be synonymous with spam or the sending of unwanted or unsolicited bulk email of a marketing or otherwise offensive nature.

[MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com) is supposed to be a good and easy email service provider, though I have never used it. I have used SparkList and Responsys. SparkList may be easy enough for you to use, but Responsys is a bit difficult and probably more than you need.

Here is a [comprehensive list](http://www.emailvendorselection.com/email-service-provider-list/) of ESP's.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database something like this:

+----+------+------+
|  id  |Name|email|
+----+------+------+
Then you can very much send a mail. First of all you need to setup your message you want to send in a variable called `$msg`. Here is a demo version for your problem.

```
<?php
$msg = "Hi this is my common message to you all";
$sub = "This is test message dnt pay attention";
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','user_name','password','DB_name')
        or die('Error in connecting the database');
$query = "SELECT * FROM EMAIL_LIST";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      mail($row['email'], $sub, $msg);
      echo 'Sent to '.$row['email'];
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, when you create database, you place the email field as unique type, so the email field does not store a duplicate record. For sending the email you also have to choose some pricing service from http://www.bulkreply.com/#pricing .